# Excel Change cell value based on dropdown option selected

Tags: excel, vba, list

Cell `F10` is a dropdown list that offers Yes, No or can be set to blank. This is made from a named list using Data Validation List with the source set to my named list.

When an option is selected in `F10` or the cell is cleared I want to update `H10`.

If `F10 = Yes` then `H10` should contain `Allowed`, If `F10 = No` or is empty `H10` should be empty, but editable by the user.

I will need to copy this down to other rows on the same worksheet.

I've spent the last hour googling, but haven't found any way to do this.

Can someone advise how it can be done.  Thanks

Comment: You can use an `IF()` formula to apply the value of "Allowed", but if the user overwrites this value the formula will not be applied to that cell in future. To avoid this you'll need to use VBA - if that's acceptable please include it as a tag.

Comment: Tag added, VBA is ok to use. Can you advise how I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the VBA editor and enter this code into the worksheet module (by default it's named `Sheet1 (Sheet1)`):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each cell In Target
      If cell.Column = 6 And cell.Row >= 10 And cell.Column <= 100 Then
        If cell.Value = "Yes" Then
          cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Allowed"
        Else
          cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = ""
        End If
      End If
    Next cell
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Note that the comparison is case-sensitive - you may want to change it to `If LCase([F10]) = "yes" Then ...`

Comment: Thanks that works well. Is there anyway to allow this to work on a range of rows ?  `F10:F100` updating `H10:H100` ?

Comment: There is indeed - see the paragraph about using `Target`.

Comment: Thanks, Using Target.Row & Target.Column I can work out the row and column selected, but I'm not sure how to procced from there. Any idea. Thanks

Comment: Solution updated to accommodate a range from rows 10 to 100 and to gracefully handle changes to multiple cells.